# Add a total to output of bash script

Tags: bash, function, for-loop, while-loop

I am running a bash script that looks through error logs and produces a report that prints in a Mac Terminal.

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
This error report is derived from Command Logs from ________ to __________.

IP addresses:

109.xx.xxx.xxx

Error Codes List: 

(code 12)
(code 30)

Common Errors - Count: 

Code 2: 
Code 10: 
Code 11: 
Code 12: 237
Code 14: 
Code 20: 
Code 23: 
Code 30: 5
Code 35: 
Code 37: 
Code 52: 
/usr/local/bin/backerr: line 45: `$skipping': not a valid identifier
Total: 242

Total Files Transferred: 
3558

Count complete.

The following are details for each error:   
// all of the 242 above-referenced lines //

Skipped files: 
// lists all of the lines that have the word 'skipping\ ' //
```

As you can see, I do not have the correct identifier:

```
    /usr/local/bin/backerr: line 45: `$skipping': not a valid identifier
```

This is the code I have to detect the lines with 'skipping\ ' in them, count the total, and print the total under the Code XX: total above. Also, I want the 'skipping\ ' total to add to 'Total: 242'.

```
  count=()
  total=0

  while read skipping; do
        (( count[$skipping]++, total++ ))      
  done < <(grep 'skipping\ ' $input_variable)

  for $skipping in $input_variable; do
    echo "Skipped: ${count[$skipping]}"
  done
```

My expected output of the "Common Errors - Count:" section should be as follows:

```
    Common Errors - Count: 

    Code 2: 
    Code 10: 
    Code 11: 
    Code 12: 237
    Code 14: 
    Code 20: 
    Code 23: 
    Code 30: 5
    Code 35: 
    Code 37: 
    Code 52: 
    Skipped: 107 (I made up this number for this question)
    Total: 349
```

I am stuck here. Please help.

As a work-around, instead of using the code below:

```
      while read skipping; do
            (( count[$skipping]++, total++ ))      
      done < <(grep 'skipping\ ' $input_variable)

      for $skipping in $input_variable; do
        echo "Skipped: ${count[$skipping]}"
      done
```

I replaced that with:

```
  echo "Total Skipped Files: " ; egrep -c 'skipping' $input_variable ;
```

But, this does not really produce the ideal outcome as I originally envisioned.

Comment: why `< <` and why not `<`

Comment: @SMA: [Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html): treats the output of a command like a file.

Comment: Underneath all of the Code totals (Code 2: 
Code 10: 
Code 11: 
Code 12: 237
Code 14: 
Code 20: 
Code 23: 
Code 30: 5
Code 35: 
Code 37: 
Code 52:)' I would like to have the a row that says `Skipped: 'n'' where is 'n' is the total. Then, I would like to add the Skipped total to the Total at the bottom. Do you understand?

Comment: I just updated the question with the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm but how are you getting `107` and `349` numbers from above input?

Comment: For the purpose of this question, I made up a number, 107. I added that number to 242, which is the total in my current output.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop shouldn't have a dollar sign for the indexing variable:

```
for skipping in $input_variable; do
   ^^^
```

Comment: I did that, but I get `/usr/local/bin/script: line 44: filename: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@filename"'

Comment: @technerdius Where is "filename" in your script?

Comment: filename is $input_variable